# How to get the host name of a network device by IP in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

If I know the IP of the devices, how do get the host name and other details of those devices in the current WiFi network?

Comment: There is no easy way; You can query the inaddr.arpa domain in DNS, but most devices on a typical WiFi network won't have those entries.  Some devices may expose their host name through SNMP, but again this is not common.

Comment: Okay. thanks. @Paulw11